# why does my file append make a new line while i didn't specify it?

Tags: autohotkey

i have made this script but the file append part in the end that makes a .bat file makes a new line after the variable %Ipconfig% was specified. why does it do that an how do i stop it from doing that so that it writes this within the .bat file:

```
:loop
ping 192.168.0.123 -l 65500 -w 1 -n 1
:goto :loop
```

instead of this:

```
:loop
ping 192.168.0.123
 -l 65500 -w 1 -n 1
:goto :loop
```

```
#NoEnv  ; Recommended for performance and compatibility with future AutoHotkey releases.
; #Warn  ; Enable warnings to assist with detecting common errors.
SendMode Input  ; Recommended for new scripts due to its superior speed and reliability.
SetWorkingDir %A_ScriptDir%  ; Ensures a consistent starting directory.

FileDelete, %A_Temp%\Temporarybat.bat
FileDelete, %A_Temp%\ip_docu.txt

TempFile=%A_Temp%\ip_temp.txt
Run %comspec% /c "ipconfig > %TempFile%",,Hide
Loop, read, C:\Users\Gebruiker\AppData\Local\Temp\ip_temp.txt, C:\Users\Gebruiker\AppData\Local\Temp\ip_docu.txt
{
    if InStr(A_LoopReadLine, "IPv4")
        FileAppend, %A_LoopReadLine%`n
}
FileRead, Ip4Line, C:\Users\Gebruiker\AppData\Local\Temp\ip_docu.txt
Ipconfig := Substr(Ip4Line, 40)

FileAppend, 
(
:loop
ping %Ipconfig% -l 65500 -w 1 -n 1
:goto :loop
), %A_Temp%\Temporarybat.bat

MsgBox, 1, ..., don't press OK,

ifmsgbox Cancel
exitapp

ifmsgbox OK
loop, 1
{
Run %comspec% /c %A_Temp%\Temporarybat.bat, , max
}
```

Comment: I'd assume that `Ipconfig := Substr(Ip4Line, 40)` will begin at position `40`, and as you've not included a length, it has also captured the `\`n`.

Comment: Out of interest, does it change things if you use `\`r\`n` instead?

Comment: indeed including a length fixes the issue, but it also forms a new issue. because there could be a case where the substr that im copying is longer so i cant include a length. and using `'r'n`  doesn't work so is there any other way i could solve this without specifying a length?

Answer (score 0):

I have now fixed the issue by using StringLen to determine how long the string is and then using that length to copy the right part of the whole string. and the script now works.